# Mdadm slow raid6 creation

Tags: raid, mdadm

Currently I am creating raid 6 on 4 4TB hdds. When I use the command

```
"cat /proc/mdstat"
```

The returning info tells me I'm 57.9% with 26516.7 min speed 1032K/sec
That seems like a really long time. The first 45% or so went by in under an hour but since then it all has slowed to halt. During that time I did format md0 to ext4 but to my understanding this was something I can do.

the command I used to create the raid was

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --verbose --level=6 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing this slowness would be appreciated. I don't really want to start using the raid too much until I know everything is setup.

Comment: This might help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html. Anyway I hope that it has finished since :)